# Ionic and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

Please forgive me for my little knowledge about this, but I have just started using Ionic to develop a hybrid app. Ideally i wanted to use my own javascript and so far it doesn't seem to work. Is this a conflict with Angular? I want my own external JS file so I can handle what happens with inputs and don't want to use Angular. Any info would be appreciated.

As to what doesn't work, i'm trying to use innerHTML to replace a value on page load and it seems to load in before the DOM so I get an error in the console. Tried moving the placement of the external js file reference but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should not be using innerHTML. Angular has this built in using data-binding:

```
<div>{{aVariableTiedTo$Scope}}</div>
```

Where aVariableTiedTo$Scope is a property defined in your controller on your $scope object.

Comment: okay thanks. Am i still able to use my own javascript for other aspects then?

Comment: Yeah, you can definitely use your own javascript, but Angular is built to be able to replace nearly every piece of javascript you could write that would interact with your UI. I strongly recommend that if you go with Angular, to understand it fully. There are a ton of goodies in there, but it will take some learning to get used to.